# How do install CentOS 7.6 using security profiles?

Tags: centos, security

Apparently CentOS 7.3's installer had a screen where you had the option of telling Anaconda to use a particular "security profile" for the install.

Is there any way to invoke this during an install of CentOS 7.6? Perhaps there is a kickstart syntax.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-syntax#idm140037266018192